# I wish to loop through an array but need to check 2 different sets of integers in the one array

Tags: php

I have created an array of 5 integers and I wish to loop these through a            multidimensional array with 5 arrays inside(containing 5 integers each). If any numbers        match I echo these out at the end. So far the program works fairly well. My issues are:

```
 1.how do I insure all integers in $drawnum are unique, I.E when I create the random number array no numbers will repeat.
```

1. The first five integers in $ticketnum and $drawnum are between 1 - 50.
   3.I wish to add 2 integers at the end of $ticketnum and $drawnum that range between 1 - 13.

   1. How do I run a loop through each array so the first 5 integers of $drawnum will check the first 5 integers of $ticketnum.
   2. How do I run a loop through each array so the last 2 integers of $drawnum will check the last 2 integers of $ticketnum.

here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$rand6 = rand(1, 10);
$rand7 = rand(1, 10);
$rand8 = rand(1, 10);
$rand9 = rand(1, 10);
$rand10 = rand(1, 10);
$randstar = rand (1, 13);
$randstar1 = rand (1, 13);
$compare = 0;
$one = 0;
$two = 0;
$three = 0;
$four = 0;
$five = 0;

//Begin loop
for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++){
$x = 0;
$rand6 = rand(1, 50);
$rand7 = rand(1, 50);
$rand8 = rand(1, 50);
$rand9 = rand(1, 50);
$rand10 = rand(1, 50);

// I want to loop this random number array through the multidimensional array
$drawnum = array($rand6,$rand7,$rand8,$rand9,$rand10);  

 $ticketnum = array(
 array(32,22,6,14,33),
 array(1,14,16,48,8),                                                                          
array(26,12,7,15,2),
array(21,18,25,44,50),
array(38,50,18,19,32),
    );

//compare the 2 arrays to see if any numbers match.
$compare = array_intersect($drawnum, $ticketnum[$x]);   
    $ans = count($compare);
        if ($ans == 1){
            $one = $one + 1;
                    }
        if ($ans == 2){
            $two = $two + 1;
                    }
        if ($ans == 3){
            $three = $three + 1;
                        }
        if ($ans == 4){
            $four = $four + 1;
                    }
        if ($ans == 5){
            $five = $five + 1;
                        }
            $x++;
            }
            echo "1 Number = " . $one . "</br>";
            echo "2 Number = " . $two . "</br>";
            echo "3 Number = " . $three . "</br>";
            echo "4 Number = " . $four . "</br>";
            echo "5 Number = " . $five . "</br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use PHP's `foreach` and `in_array` functions to loop through arrays and check if values are appearing in the arrays?

Comment: I understand how foreach and in_array work but the issue Im having is how to go about writing the code to loop through the loop.